# How can I track which tab or content script a message came from?

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, content-script

In a Firefox add-on I need to track which tab messages are associated with. The content script will send data to the `main.js`. Later, when the user clicks the extension's button in the toolbar it will look for data associated with the active tab.

In Chrome extensions, when a message was received, I could ask which tab the message came from and track messages by the tab id. In Firefox, [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#id) have id's too, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to access them from content scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on which way you are creating the content scripts. Below is an example `main.js` file for adding content scripts with [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action'),
    pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod'),
    data = require('sdk/self').data;   

// Map of messages keyed by tab id
var messages = {};

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: 'http://www.example.com',
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url('my-script.js')
  ],
  onAttach: function(worker){

    // Get the tab id from the worker
    var tabId = worker.tab.id;

    // Save the message
    worker.port.on('message', function(message){
      messages[tabId] = message;
    });

    // Delete the messages when the tab is closed
    // to prevent a memory leak
    worker.on('detach', function(){
      delete messages[tabId];
    });
  }
});

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: 'my-extension',
  label: 'Example',
  icon: {
    '16': './icon-16.png',
    '32': './icon-32.png',
    '64': './icon-64.png'
  },
  onClick: function(state){

    // Retrieve the message associated with the
    // currently active tab, if there is one
    var message = messages[tabs.activeTab.id];

    // Do something with the message
  }
});
```

I also recommend reading [Content Scripts - Interacting with Page Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Interacting_with_page_scripts) and [Content Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/content_worker) for a better understanding about what's going on and how to adapt it to your situation.